# Button hover effect not showing after button is clicked/focused

Tags: css, focus, hover, vaadin

I'm developing a web application using the Vaadin framework.

I have a Button styled as BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK and have an icon showing.
The button is assigned a CSS class which has a hover state, when the button is hovered the icon is replaced. Simple enough.

However, I find that once the button is clicked, the hover stops working until you click elsewhere. The button seem to be focused after clicking and then the hover effect doesn't work.

Does anyone know a way to work abound this, either using Vaadin or CSS?

**EDIT:** HTML and CSS added

HTML:

```
<div style="height: 26px; width: 292px; overflow: hidden; float: left; padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 0px;">
  <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;">
    <div class="v-button v-button-link link v-button-m2m-refreshbutton m2m-refreshbutton" tabindex="0" role="button">
      <span class="v-button-wrap">
        <img class="v-icon" alt="" src="/M2M/VAADIN/themes/m2m/../m2m/img/refresh_.png">
        <span class="v-button-caption"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.m2m-refreshbutton:hover {
    background: url("../m2m/img/refresh_hover.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: please provide the html markup and related CSS

Comment: @Libin Sorry, thought the markup and css would be redundant for the problem. Anyhow, it's added now.

Comment: All right, really cute to down vote without having the balls to say why.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when I used Vaadin to create Liferay portlet. I was able to fix it by changing the CSS Vaadin uses (by using the [CSS Inject Add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/cssinject), but it is also possible to just provide a custom Vaadin theme). The piece of CSS that worked for me is:

```
.v-button:active .v-button-wrap, .v-button.v-pressed .v-button-wrap, .v-button:focus .v-button-wrap {
background: #d4d4d4 url(/html/themes/classic/images/portlet/header_bg.png) repeat-x 0 0 !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it is a better idea to do this with background-images in CSS only.

You should also use an `<a></a>` tag for this because older Internet Explorers for example don't apply link states to HTML elements other than `<a></a>`.

Basically getting different images for the different states of a link can be done like this:

HTML:

```
<a class="someClass" href="location"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.someClass {
    background-image: url(path_from_css_file/link.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
}

.someClass:hover {
    background-image: url(path_from_css_file/link_hover.png);
}

.someClass:focus {
    background-image: url(path_from_css_file/link_focus.png);
}

.someClass:active {
    background-image: url(path_from_css_file/link_active.png);
}

.someClass:visited {
    background-image: url(path_from_css_file/link_visited.png);
}
```

Comment: It would be even more elegant if you would use one CSS sprite instead of different state images. You can read about sprites here for example: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: hi mwld, thanks for the post. I'm afraid however that it doesn't touch the problem I'm having. It more has to do with the Vaadin framework rather than CSS and the generated markup involved. I need a way that makes the button lose focus after clicking it. I know about sprites, and it's in the pipeline. But it's not a good idea to use sprites during development since that will involve additional work just altering the sprite for every new resource that is added. It's better to do once you're ready for release.

Comment: Ok, but couldn't you then just apply the hover image to the `:focus` (and/or `:active`) state?

Comment: Well no, I don't want the button to ever be focused. It's a refresh button. You click it, a component refreshes, and the button goes back to it's default idle state. The problem is that when I click it it gets stuck in the focus state until I click elsewhere, and during the time it's focused the :hover state can't be triggered.

Comment: Ok, if you want to make an element loose its focus after being clicked then you can use JavaScript´s `blur()` function for this like: `$('.someClass').blur();`

Comment: Thanks mwld, but as the question suggests I'm developing in Vaadin. I don't have control over the markup or the JavaScript that is involved. The problem has to be solved using the Vaadin framework.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript it is possible.

first get the button

```
buttonElement = document.getElementById("yourID");
```

Add Event listener to the button and call a function.

```
ButtonElement.addEventListener('click', nofocus);
```

create the function

```
function nofocus () {
this.blur();
}
```

whenever you click the button. focus state will gone.