# How to do Vaadin Button Mouseovers

Tags: java, vaadin

Can anyone give me basic steps to add a mouseover to an image in my project? I have the button created and styled like a link, but I would like the image to change to a different one of same size when the user's cursor is on top of image. I know that I have to add something to the style.css file. I've read several forum threads and can't seem to get it to work.

```
workingButton.setStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
workingButton.setIcon(new FileResource(new File(basepath + "help.png")));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Coloring button link background area when it's hovered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20403845/642706) and another: [Button hover effect not showing after button is clicked/focused](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11757522/642706).

Comment: Thanks, but these links don't specifically address my issue. I just want to change the image when hovered over. I have an image with text, and an image with a glow effect around it. I just want the glow effect image to show when hovered.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Button.setIcon` method will add an `img` element, which means the `src` attribute can't be altered using CSS (or at least not reliably for all browsers).

However, you could achieve what you wanted by using a CSS [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) along with the pseudo class of `:hover` for the button image (rather than the `setIcon` method on the button). In order to do this:

i. Ensure the 2 images (normal and hover) are accessible in your project

ii. Add the button in your server side code:

```
Button cssButton = new Button("CSS Hover");
cssButton.setStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
cssButton.setId("cssBtn");
```

iii. Add the following CSS:

```
#cssBtn {
   padding: 0 40px;
   background-image: url("images/help.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#cssBtn:hover {
  padding: 0 40px;
  background-image: url("images/help_invert.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This will achieve the following result:

Normally:

[image]

When hovered over:

[image]